# adding a delay to this jquery function

Tags: jquery, image, fadein

I am using jquery to swap an img src. Is there any way to add a fade effect so that the image fades in and out rather than a straight instant swap?

cheers

```
<img class="imgswap" data-alt-src="img1.jpg" src="img2.jpg" />
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
    $('img.imgswap').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following functions:

```
.mouseover(function() { 
    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        //do the swapping
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="imgswap" data-alt-src="img1.jpg" src="img2.jpg" />

var sourceSwap = function () {
    var newSource = $(this).data('alt-src');

    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).data('alt-src', $(this).attr('src'));
        $(this).attr('src', newSource);

        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('img.imgswap').mouseover(sourceSwap);
});
```

But I am not sure, that this would be in right context in that function.

**UPD:** http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/X8ycM/1/

Fix of "really fast hovering" is here.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('processing')) {
    return;
}

$(this).addClass('processing');
```

And in the end:

```
$(this).removeClass('processing');
```

Comment: Nearly there thanks.

If you see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X8ycM/

when you hover over and out really fast you just end up with the same image

Comment: @sam sorry, misunderstand. what do you mean?

Comment: Well I want image1 to show. On hover ( and whilst staying hovered) I want image2 to be shown. Then on mouseout I want image1 to be shown.

But in the fiddle, if you keep hovering over, you'll see that the bear sometimes becomes the image on mouseout

Comment: Okay, I see only one way: http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/X8ycM/2/ There are more code npw, but it works.